# Apache 2.0 License redistribute with package/class name change

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0, license-notice, relicensing

I have been modifying an open source Apache 2.0 licensed project and now I want to re-distribute the code under the same license but under MY SET OF REPOS as the original company isn't wanting my changes part of theirs.

The catch is that the original company has copyright on their name and they've used it at many places as the package name, class names etc. Even some folders / paths are named with their company name.

I want to remove those to make it a more neutral approach. Doing so changes 90% of the files, there are about 250 files in total.

As per Apache 2.0 License, I need to add significant changes in the file itself. What is the best way to do it, considering :

- I will re-distribute source code = Yes.
- I will change package name in approx 250 files and make more modifications in future.
- They have no copyright or notice file anywhere except their package.json which mentions their company name, which I am ready to keep intact, but no-where else in the code.

So, What exactly should I write if I have to write a notice on top of each 250 files?

Comment: You plan to create a fork, so https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo might give you some answers. As long as you keep the items mentioned in Section 4 of the license https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 you should be OK. Section 2 gives you a copyright license, so you should not be concerned about using their name in the way they have included it already in their files.

Comment: My Question is about 4.2 which says : You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that You changed the files; and

So do I need to add statements to all 250 files?

Comment: Yes, what's the problem with this requirement? Good old vi was already able to do that in a batch job 30 years ago.

Comment: No problem in writing, but what should be the ideal way to write it? 
What all should be written there?

Comment: This has been discussed multiple times on this site. Try using SEARCH to find what you exactly need. Some of the first answers will be ... https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/apache-2-0-license-notice-changelog and https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/how-to-label-and-license-derivative-works-made-under-apache-license-version-2-0

Comment: I would not bother renaming the classes to avoid their company name. Yes, they have a trademark for their brand, but that doesn't mean you're necessarily forbidden from using this name. Looking at other projects that had similar history, they avoided renaming the classes as well. For example, the "Jenkins" CI server was based on "Hudson", a name that was claimed by Oracle. Jenkins rebranded the project as a whole, but to this day still has classes in a Hudson namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It's trademark, not copyright issue.

I recommend you adding "Changelog.txt" file, because you didn't modified file, but it's name. But if you modify class names, you should change that class name in other files.

Then add a changelog in that files "Updated classes names".

**THIS POST IS NOT A LEGAL ADVICE**